# From SIMULINK to workspace FFT?

Tags: matlab, simulink, workspace

If I want to plot the PSD of a simple sinusoidal wave in Matlab, I would do something like the following:

```
Fs = 1000;
t = 0:1/Fs:1-(1/Fs);
x = cos(2*pi*100*t) ;

N = length(x);
xdft = fft(x);
xdft = xdft(1:N/2+1);
psdx = (1/(Fs*N)) * abs(xdft).^2;
psdx(2:end-1) = 2*psdx(2:end-1);
freq = 0:Fs/length(x):Fs/2;

plot(freq,10*log10(psdx))
grid on
```

But suppose, for simplicity, I have a sinewave generator in SIMULINK and I need to plot the PSD. I did something like the following:
[image]

Then I got the variable called "Sinwave", **how can I possibly apply the above Matlab code to plot the PSD?**

Please note that the variable Sinewave is *1x1 double time series*. I tried to just replace x with Sinwave, but it didn't work.

**Update: Applying the answers**

I applied what's recommended down, but I have a different output than if I do it with Matalb. Here is the code I used:

```
Fs = 1000;
x = Sinwave.Data;
N = length(x);
dft = fft(x);
dft = dft(1:N/2+1);
psd = (1/(Fs*N)) * abs(dft).^2;
psd(2:end-1) = 2*psd(2:end-1);
freq = 0:Fs/length(x):Fs/2;

plot(freq,10*log10(psd))
grid on
```

This one for the SIMULINK-exported sinewave 
[image]

However, the one from the matlab code is like the following:
[image]

I need the output to be like this from matalb ***with all these ripples in the noise floor***. ***How can I get the exact output?***

Please note I've used the exact values for both.

**Update 2: SIMULINK sinewave setup**

**1- Sinewave block**

[image]

**2- To workspace block**

[image]

**3- Solver**

[image]

Comment: Check your sampling frequency in the Sine wave block. Plot both data on the same figure and see where they are different. You may want to post your update as a different question since it is about the sine wave data and not about logging to workspace.

Comment: 1- I would say it's the same questions. Because it's about correctly exporting data to Matlab. 2- I don't need to plot on the same figure because the differences are quit big and really obvious. You only plot on same figure if differences are small. 3- Sampling frequency and everything is exactly the same as mentioned before.

Comment: I get the same result as Simulink by using the exact code you also have. Did you set the Simulink solver to fixed-timestep and the correct sampling frequency?

Comment: That's weird, because I set yes the solver step-size to fixed 1e-3 which is equal to the sample freq Fs. Also, I tried to change the solver step-size to 1e-4, 1e-5  but still same output. What are we possibly overlooking here?

Comment: I meant the sine wave data to be plotted on the same figure. Not psd.

Comment: @AhmedWas if your problem persists, can you please show us the setup of your sine wave source?

Comment: Update done. Thanks

Comment: @AhmedWas see my edited answer - does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you take a close look at your `Sinewave` variable, i.e. by simply typing its name in the command prompt, you will see the following:

```
  >>  Sinwave
  timeseries

  Common Properties:
            Name: ''
            Time: [51x1 double]
        TimeInfo: [1x1 tsdata.timemetadata]
            Data: [51x1 double]
        DataInfo: [1x1 tsdata.datametadata]

  More properties, Methods
```

It contains different fields, e.g. `Time` and `Data`, which are both arrays. We could simply try plotting these for example:

```
plot(Sinwave.Time, Sinwave.Data)
```

And indeed, this gives us a nice plot of your sine wave. We could now try replacing the variable `t` with `Sinewave.Time` and `x` with `Sinewave.Data`, which allows us to plot the PSD.

If you don't know the sampling frequency, you can use the `Sinewave.TimeInfo` - which contains the number of samples, and the start and end time, to calculate the sampling frequency `Fs`.

---

Responding to your edited question: the time vector `t`, which you create with your MATLAB code, is `0 : 0.001 : 0.999` and is of length 1000. Your Simulink simulation, however, runs from `t=0` to `t=1` in steps of `0.001`, thus your resulting time- and data-vectors are of length 1001! The calculation assumes that the step size is `1/1001` instead of `1/1000`, leading to different results. To solve that problem, change the *Stop Time* in the simulation setup to 0.999. Then, the resulting vectors are of correct size, and you get the same result as the MATLAB calculation.

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But please check the update as the output is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Timeseries object contains a Data field which should contain the sinewave data. You can do `x = Sinwave.Data;` and can then use the rest of your code. Alternatively you can also set the "Save format" property of "To workspace" block to "Array". This will make Sinwave a regular MATLAB array. You can then simply replace x with Sinwave.

Comment: Kindly check the update. I still have a problem with the output.